# Mount a Host Directory as a Data Volume in docker?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

when i try to mount a host directory as data volume in docker its not mount any directory to docker container(image).
When i run

```
sudo docker run -t -i --name web -v /home/rponna/src/webapp:/opt/webapp ramnathreddy
```

it returns container id

```
7dcc03c397d56514015220a073c9e951478bf84aceb90b880bb93a5716079212
```

But when i run that container it will not show any files in opt/webapp (its empty).

Comment: when the container is running try this: "docker exec -i -t web /bin/bash" this will execute /bin/bash as second command in your container and attaches you over a tty. Then you will be in the running container and you can inspect the volumes.

Comment: when i run sudo docker exec -i -t web /bin/bash
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Container web is not running 
      $ sudo docker start web
web
$ sudo docker ps -l 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
09977f0f8684        ramnath:latest      "/bin/bash"         3 minutes ago       Exited (0) 9 seconds ago                       web                 
$ sudo docker exec -i -t web /bin/bash
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Container web is not running

Comment: if you can't run exec, it looks like your container has exited.

can you post the output from ```docker logs web``` ?

Comment: Correct, your container is broken and can't start as deamon "-d". Start your container as interactive, by replacing "-d" with "-i -t". Then you will see all outputs of the container in your shell.

Comment: When i run 
"$ sudo docker run -d -P --name web -v /dockerdatavolume/src/webapp:/dockerhostdatavolue/opt/webapp ramnathreddy   "
 it  returns  "acbf548f7f209a21bca4cb9631aee80ae80e7853724e9a8c0e4446718cf4e61c   "(container ). 
I commit that container as image with 
"$  sudo docker commit acbf548f7f2 ramnath"                                             
it returns "cfd4915e8317ca7a0350c70ccd101838dbc4528d711209a922ae06abcd9e6f09"

 Again open that image with  command but it will not mount any host directory in to container 
$ sudo docker run -t -i ramnath bash